# Please help identify LEGO from this picture of the base

Tags: set-identification

Difficult to find which set this piece belongs to.

[image]

Could anyone give me more information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Baseplate, Raised 32 x 32 Three Level with Ogel Center Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6092pb02#T=C)

[image]